# Bars/Columns not showing up in bar plat in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to make a bar graph in R, and am following code that has been successful in the past. But, for some reason the plot is only showing the error bars for the graph, and not the bars themselves.

The data pulls from the following data frame

```
plr_sum2 <- data_summary(plr2, varname="Ranking", 
                        groupnames="Choice")
```

Which includes the following data

| Choice | Ranking | sd | se | Friend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2.98 | 1.27 | 0.08 | Incorrect |
| 1 | 3.67 | 1.26 | 0.08 | Correct |

I have tried making the graph using both the "Choice" variable and the "Friend" variable for the bars (they are synonymous) and get the same error

```
graph5<-ggplot(plr_sum2, aes(x=Friend, y=Ranking) ) +
  geom_col(fill="lightblue") +
  theme_bw()+
  geom_errorbar( aes(x=Friend, ymin=Ranking-se, ymax=Ranking+se, width=0.2), colour="black", alpha=0.9, size=0.5)+
  labs(y = "Social Preference", x = "Register Choice")+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("Correct","Incorrect"))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(1,5))
graph5
```

When I use this code I get the warning message, "Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_col)" and the graph shows up with only the error bars.

Comment: Get rid of the `limits` or adjust them. As bars start at zero while you have set the lower limit to 1 they are dropped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error stems from `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1,5))`: the y-range doesn't include 0, therefore the bar is not drawn. If you want your plot to start at `y = 1`, use `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1, 5)`:

```r
require("ggplot2")
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.1.3
plr_sum2 <- data.frame(choice = c(0,1),
                 Ranking = c(2.98,3.67),
                 sd = c(1.27, 1.26),
                 se = 0.08,
                 Friend = c("Incorrect", "Correct"))

ggplot(plr_sum2, aes(x=Friend, y=Ranking) ) +
  geom_col(fill="lightblue") +
  theme_bw()+
  geom_errorbar( aes(x=Friend, ymin=Ranking-se, ymax=Ranking+se), width=0.2, colour="black", alpha=0.9, size=0.5)+
  labs(y = "Social Preference", x = "Register Choice")+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("Correct","Incorrect")) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1, 5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you!! The response is on a 1-5 scale, so I was trying to make that clear in the graph -- this is the perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your y limits are incorrectly specified (must include 0). Additionally, there is no need for your second last line of `scale_x_discrete`:

```r
ggplot(plr_sum2, aes(x = Friend, y = Ranking)) +
  geom_col(fill = "lightblue") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=Friend, ymin=Ranking-se, ymax=Ranking+se, width=0.2), colour="black", alpha=0.9, size=0.5)+
  labs(y = "Social Preference", x = "Register Choice") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,5))
```

[image]